# Python code to open with another program?

Tags: python

I have a program I want to open when I open Chrome. Instead of opening them separately, I want it to automatically start when Chrome starts. How would I write code to have the program attach itself to Chrome? I don't want the program to start on startup, just when Chrome starts. I know I can right click on the Chrome icon on my desktop and change the properties to open both programs but I want to know how to do the same thing with code.

Comment: You'll need to have a background process or service that listens for when Chrome starts up (by checking running processes).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options.  Which you should choose depends on lots of things.  Sorry for being so vague, but your question does not give any details besides the name Chrome.

1. How ever you start Chrome, e. g. by a button or menu of your window manager, maybe you can tweak that button or menu to start both programs.  This is probably the simplest solution, but of course it bears the risk that a different event starts Chrome (e. g. clicking a link in a mail program).  This would then pass-by your Program.
2. You can write a daemon process which you start via login-scripts at login time.  That daemon would try to figure out when you start Chrome (e. g. by polling the process table) and react by starting your accompanying program.
3. You can configure Chrome so that it starts your program upon starting time.  How to do this is a whole new question in itself with lots of answers; options include at least writing a plugin for Chrome which does what you want.
4. You can have your program up and running all the time (started via login scripts, i. e. too early) but stay invisible and passive until Chrome starts up.  This is basically the same as option 2, just that your program is itself that daemon.

In case you tell us more, we probably can give narrower and thus more fitting answers.

Comment: #3 is kinda what I was going for. Is a plugin the only way to do this? I mentioned that physically, I could just right click on the desktop icon (this is the way I start Chrome) and change the properties to include my program. This is what I wanted to program to do. For the program to change that to include itself when the desktop icon is clicked.

Comment: If I have the program start on startup, then would it necessarily need administrator privileges? 

Also, what if the program renamed chrome.exe to chrome1.exe and then the program is named chrome.exe in the same location. So however chrome starts, it will start chrome.exe (now my program) and then my program will start chrome1.exe.

Comment: Windows?  No clue, sorry.  In general it should be possible to replace a program by a wrapper (like you suggested with the renamings) and I have done so several times on Linux.  But keep in mind that this will not be compatible with the typical update mechanisms (updating Chrome can happen automatically and will not know that now `chrome1.exe` needs to be updated).